# display NONE as a value for missing ansible_facts

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I perform a playbook to gather `ansible_facts` from several servers therefore creating a hardware report, some `ansible_facts` does not exist (`devices`, `net_adapters`...), I want to display `NONE` as a value for these unavailable `ansible_facts` instead of getting an error which prevents my playbook to run without stopping.

Comment: Please elaborate your question to get right answer, explain the use case / context, that will help other contributor to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#default) Jinja filter for this.

Given this playbook on an host where I do not have `net_adapters`

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:  
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.net_adapters | default('NONE') }}"
```

This yields the recap

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "NONE"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: good idea, but i run my playbook againt a several servers which have a various hardware config, i want to display none msj just for those didn't have a specific hard.

Comment: Which will happen, if the key `net_adapters` is difined, it will display what is there, otherwise, the default. > *If the value is undefined it will return the passed default value, otherwise the value of the variable:* From the doc: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#default

Comment: I m so thankful for you bro, i tested it and it works well,